# How to make a graphical frame when no other graphical frames are present?

Tags: frames, server

One way would be to somehow guess a display and do `(make-frame-on-display display)`. However, `(getenv "DISPLAY")` does not give a sensible answer (e.g ":" or nil).

I tried to explicitly specify `window-system` but that also does not work without knowing a display.

One use-case would be to make a togglable persistent emacs frame available on a key press.

Comment: `make-frame-on-display` should prompt you with a list of the displays it knows about

Comment: If you are running a GUI, even if you are running `emacs -nw` from a terminal emulator, the terminal emulator should have a setting for DISPLAY (`echo $DISPLAY`) and emacs should inherit that setting (if not, say `export DISPLAY` before starting `emacs -nw`). Giving that value to `make-frame-on-display` should then open a frame. If you are running emacs from the console, you are out of luck of course.

Comment: @rpluim, I can't reproduce on emacs 26.3. What is your version of emacs?

Comment: @NickD I'm running emacs daemon. At the very beginning it creates a frame on "initial_terminal". This frame has no access to GUI and has weird `$DISPLAY` value (as stated in the post)

Comment: @grepcake I missed that you were running daemon. `emacsclient -c` should create a graphical frame for you.

Comment: @rpluim if what you said is the case (prompt for a list of displays) I can just study the mechanism and get the answer. As for `emacsclient -c`, it will create a new frame every time which just makes the idea of a persistent frame completely pointless. I want to create a new frame only when there are no frames present.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding something: if you only have the daemon, and no graphical frames, run `emacsclient -c`. If you do have a frame already, just run `emacsclient`. (I'll admit I let emacsclient create frames all the time: they're transient as far as I'm concerned)

Comment: @rpluim I can see how I can do it from, e.g a bash script. But that's not cross-platform. I would rather like to implement this behaviour (no graphical frames --- create one, otherwise --- operate on existing ones) from inside emacs, in an elisp function.

Comment: You can get that if you use emacs normally, ie not in daemon mode: the default action of `emacsclient` is to reuse an existing frame in that case.

Comment: @rpluim, yeah, but I'm writing a package, so I would like that to work for everyone, including people who use emacs daemon